# Trap command in script works when called from CLI but not when used in a PBS job

Tags: bash, unix, error-handling, pbs, bash-trap

I have the following simple bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail
set -o errtrace
set -o errexit

PROGNAME=$0

trap 'echo "${PROGNAME} recieved signal EXIT" | mailx -s "EXIT" "someone@anywhere.com"' EXIT
trap 'echo "${PROGNAME} recieved signal SIGHUP" | mailx -s "SIGHUP" "someone@anywhere.com"' SIGHUP
trap 'echo "${PROGNAME} recieved signal SIGINT" | mailx -s "SIGINT" "someone@anywhere.com"' SIGINT
trap 'echo "${PROGNAME} recieved signal SIGQUIT" | mailx -s "SIGQUIT" "someone@anywhere.com"' SIGQUIT
trap 'echo "${PROGNAME} recieved signal SIGTERM" | mailx -s "SIGTERM" "someone@anywhere.com"' SIGTERM

sleep 1000
```

When I run this script from the command line: i.e.

```
./test_script.sh
```

And then interrupt the script by sending CTRL+C I get two emails. One containing the message: "recieved signal EXIT". The other containing the message "recieved signal SIGINT".

However when I run this script as a PBS job:

```
qsub test_script.sh
```

And then wait for a minute or two and perform a qdel on the submitted job, I only recieve an email containing "recieved signal EXIT". While I also expected to get an email stating recieved signal SIGTERM, because the qdel man page states:

```
A batch job being deleted by a server will be sent a SIGTERM signal following by a SIGKILL signal
```

Does someone know why this is? Ideally I would like to recieve an email when something inside my script returns an exit code different than 0, but I would also like to recieve a different email when the script terminates earlier than expected, for instance because of a SIGINT or a SIGTERM.

Some additional information, when I modify the line:

```bsh
trap 'echo "${PROGNAME} recieved signal EXIT" | mailx -s "EXIT" "someone@anywhere.com"' EXIT
```

to

```bsh
trap 'echo "${PROGNAME} recieved signal EXIT, last command was ${BASH_COMMAND}" | mailx -s "EXIT" "someone@anywhere.com"' EXIT
```

I can see that the last command executed was "mailx -s "SIGTERM" "someone@anywhere.com" and not "sleep 1000". So it does seem to be the case the SIGTERM signal gets caught, but the subsequent trap command does not work for PBS jobs...

Comment: Just a wild guess: if `qsub` executes the script with `sh` instead of `bash`, it may not accept `SIGINT` as a valid signal name, requiring `INT` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather confusing but the problem is that the script is trapping the signal and the shell running the script isn't. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Use the $exec_with_exec option in the mom's config file. This has the pbs_mom launch the job slightly differently (using exec) which handles the issue for you. You'll need admin rights to change the config file, but this parameter is documented [here](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/12-appendices/parameters.htm?TocPath=Appendices%7CAppendix%20C%3a%20Node%20manager%20%28MOM%29%20configuration%7C_____1).
2. Configure the shell to also trap the signal (this can have unintended consequences).